# GTK+ GPX Viewer

Tags: linux, open-source, openstreetmap

I'm looking for an application that:

- Is gratis
- Is open-source
- Works on Linux
- Uses GTK+
- Uses metric units
- Can import .GPX files
- Shows OpenStreetMap
- Shows my track
- Shows a dot on the start and end of each segment
- Shows my minimum speed
- Shows my average speed
- Shows my maximum speed
- Shows the duration
- Shows the distance
- Shows a graph with my speed
- Can zoom
- Can drag

Answer (score 2):

I think this one meets all or at least allmost all of your criterias:

[Viking](https://sourceforge.net/projects/viking/):

- gratis
- open source
- linux
- gtk+
- metric
- import gpx
- show osm
- show track
- shows dots
- show statistics / speed / time etc.
- zoom and drag

It can even do more:

- elevation graph
- Bing aerial map
- ...

Install via

```
sudo apt-get install viking
```

Comment: OSM doesn't work at my machine, because it fails to download tile. I also can't figure out how I can view the statistics.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at GpsMaster (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GpsMaster). It appears to tick all your requirements apart from the GTK+ one (it's written in Java FWIW).

I've found it to be quite a useful utility for viewing GPX tracks and waypoints. The only shortcoming is that I can't see how to get it to display Imperial units (YMMV).